# ambiguous overload operator specifically in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

This is a revised question

In r, and Rcpp I have a string declared as `string def;`
I also have a data frame called `Row_Labels` that contains two-letter strings, "AA", "BB", etc.
Now I am trying to do this..

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <string.h>
//using namespace Rcpp;
//using namespace std;


// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::DataFrame process_Data(Rcpp::DataFrame df,Rcpp::DataFrame Row_Labels, Rcpp::DataFrame Column_Labels){

  Rcpp::Rcout << "Test value from 'cout' " << std::endl;
  Rcpp::Rcout << "Number of rows in df = " << df.nrow() << std::endl;

  std::string abc;
  abc = "test value";
  std::string def;
  def = "zz";

    for(int i = 0; i < Row_Labels.nrow() ; i++)
    {

      def = Row_Labels[i];  // error here

      Rcpp::Rcout << "Row_Labels = " << i;
      Rcpp::Rcout << i << " " << Row_Labels[i] << std::endl; // error here

   }


  return Rcpp::DataFrame::create(Rcpp::_["a"]= df);

}
```

I am getting an error that is... `use of overload operator'=' is ambiguous (with operand types 'string' (aka 'based_string <char, char traits <char>, allocator <char> >') and 'Proxy' (aka 'generic proxy<19>'))`

I appreciate the help and hope this revision is more helpful

Comment: Don't use `using namespace Rcpp; using namespace std;` Use explicit `::` references.

Comment: Provide _complete and reproducible_ examples. This is not one.

Comment: Thank you.  I removed the two namespace statements.  The error still occurs.  I tried to paste the complete function here, but got errors.

Comment: Just edit your question and put something reproducible. String assignment can be tricky but right we can't tell _as we don't even know your types_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a pretty simple error there:  If row and column labels are of type `DateFrame` then you cannot index as you do in `Row_Labels[i];` -- these are not vectors.  Fix: use vectors instead.  This also requires to use `length()` rather than `nrow()`.  So the following compiles fine:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::DataFrame process_Data(Rcpp::DataFrame df,
                             Rcpp::CharacterVector Row_Labels,
                             Rcpp::CharacterVector Column_Labels){

  Rcpp::Rcout << "Test value from 'cout' " << std::endl;
  Rcpp::Rcout << "Number of rows in df = " << df.nrow() << std::endl;

  std::string abc = "test value";
  std::string def = "zz";

  for(int i = 0; i < Row_Labels.length() ; i++) {
      def = Row_Labels[i];  // error here
      Rcpp::Rcout << "Row_Labels = " << i;
      Rcpp::Rcout << i << " " << Row_Labels[i] << std::endl; // error here
  }
  return Rcpp::DataFrame::create(Rcpp::_["a"]= df);
}
```

I also tightened and shortend it a little.

Comment: Thank you.  If I am calling this with data frames from R, won't the use of vectors, here cause a problem when the function is called?

Comment: Well, the proof is whether it works, and it does.  Thank you very much for the lesson.

Comment: And you can of course use `DataFrame` to carry vectors etc,  but need to then extract them.  See several examples at the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org).